# Java: Sorting an ArrayList<Object> in descending order

Tags: java, generics, collections, arraylist

My attempt to sort an ArrayList in reverse (descending) order with the following code snippet - used in a JSF managed bean to populate a dataGrid returns the error below:

```
public List<Surec> getPendingForms() {
   ...
   List<Surec> tersSiraliListe = new ArrayList<Surec>(someSet);
   Comparator<Surec> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
   Collections.sort(tersSiraliListe,comparator);
   return tersSiraliListe;
}
```

Exception:

```
...

Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /surecler/dashboard.xhtml @43,118 rendered="#{empty surecBean.pendingForms}": Error reading 'pendingForms' on type net.ozar.web.jsfmanaged.SurecBean
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:76)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:390)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.ozar.entity.DerivedFromSurec cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at net.ozar.web.jsfmanaged.SurecBean.getPendingForms(SurecBean.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:83)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:45)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    ... 31 more
```

Since I defined **comparator** as an object of type Comparator<**Surec**> I don't understand why the exception is thrown. Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: It strikes me as pretty weird - and bad - that Collections.reverseOrder() is parameterised with a plain <T>, rather than a <T extends Comparable<T>>, since it can never actually work for non-comparable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your *DerivedFromSurec* entities are not comparable. Your *Surec* class has to implement **java.lang.Comparable**.

Answer (score 4):

Does DerivedFromSurec implement Comparable ?

Unless you provide your own *Comparator* implementation, rather than the implementation given by *Collections.reverseOrder()*, you will need to implement the Comparable interface. The alternative is to supply  your own Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own comparable interface (ascending as it should be) through your custom class if you are using one and then do the following: `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());`